# User reporting seeing old website, when new one has gone live

Tags: wordpress, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I've recently put a new style live on: summerboardingcourses.co.uk

I've had report from one user that they are seeing the old website (with broken styles) on iPhone Safari browser from Poland (I am based in the UK). I can't replicate the issue, every VPN I use, or GeoLocation Screenshot tool I've used (e.g. localbrowser.com) the site is viewing correctly.

Has anyone ever had an issue like this before? I can't understand why they would be seeing the old site.

Any advice at all would be fantastic.

Thanks,
Meg

Comment: This seems to be cache in users' devices. Have you cleared the cache and CSS been updated?

Comment: I've put some meta tags in my head to try and force the browser to clear the cache, i'm also running a plugin on the site to help force the browsers to clear their cache and I use version of CSS e.g main.css?ver=1.1550224072

The user said they had cleared their cache, and that they were still having the problem. But I can't recreate.

Comment: Can you share any screenshot?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of the screenshot. You can visit our live site though: summerboardingcourses.co.uk, but I'd imagine it'll show the new styling for you if you've never visited before.

Comment: Yeah I checked the site and I couldn't find out any broken CSS. Have you changed the theme version?

Comment: Thanks, nope just pushed up some new CSS, and added some new ACF and js.

Comment: Will do like this. First clear all server cache and disable the plugin. Then add versioning to all CSS and JS files. Like `?v=1.x` like. Next add following to header `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />`
And we can have a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Return Last modified date or current date*/
function get_mod_time($file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        return date("y.m.d-H", filemtime($file));
    }
    else {
        return date('y.m.d-H');
    }
}

/* Include style */
$css_file = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css';
wp_enqueue_style( 'site-css', $css_file, array(), get_mod_time($css_file), 'all' );
```

Same think you can do for your custom JS files, you get last modified date as version name, that forces clear cache if file on server updated